# How can I avoid the offer to send a report to Apple when an assertion in my own unit-tests fails?

Tags: unit-testing, macos

I frequently write programs consisting of nothing but assertions to test my code. While debugging, OSX tries to be helpful by asking whether I would like to "Click Report to see more detailed information and send a report to Apple" whenever an assertion fails.

Is there a way to disable this feature for my programs? I am using make and g++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot, however it'll disable them system wide.

`defaults write com.apple.CrashReporter DialogType none`

Comment: Alternatively, run CrashReporterPrefs.app, available at /Developer/Applications/Utilities.

Comment: I suppose that's good enough. It didn't seem that my diligent (weekly or so) crash reports to Apple were resolved within OS X as time went by.